# Configuring ROS msg to transmit std::vector<pcl17::PointXYZRGB>

Tags: ros, pcl, msg, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am using PCL (Point Cloud Library 1.7) with ROS and I have the following problem. I want to create a publisher and subscriber  node and publish three vectors : std::vectorpcl17::PointXYZRGB, with variable size each time (The vector may contain a different number of points each time).

Can anybody help me to configure the ROS msg in order to achieve transmission?

Best,

Akis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/90531/configuring-ros-msg-to-transmit-std::vector%3Cpcl17::pointxyzrgb%3E/) by [Zoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/7726/zoid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you elaborate why you want to publish three vectors?
If you just want to publish a point cloud check the question and the answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/35368/pointcloud-library-publishing/).

[Here](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Publishing-a-vector-of-point-clouds-td2301776.html) is a quite old discussion of  what you probably want to do.

---

Originally posted by [Artem](https://answers.ros.org/users/5031/artem/) with karma: 709 on 2013-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-14**:
There's a tutorial for creating messages here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv

**Comment by [Zoid](https://answers.ros.org/users/7726/zoid/) on 2013-10-16**:
Well, I am segmenting a point cloud (taken from a Kinect sensor) and I am trying to publish a vector with the centroid points of each extracted cluster and another two vectors that contain the minimum and maximum points of each cluster. In every iteration I might extract different number of clusters and therefore my published vectors will have a variable size.

What I could do is to try publishing the cluster clouds in a single vector, instead of publishing three vectors and then extract the centroid and max/min points on the receiving ROS node.

I am quite new with ROS and PCL and that's why I need your help an advise in this matter. I went through the suggested tutorials and I am trying to understand how ros message works but I still haven't fully got it.

Any help would be greatly appreciate it. :)

Best,

Akis